# How to read VramInfo of Dxdiag using any C++ Microsoft API?

Tags: c++, directx

How to read VramInfo of Dxdiag using any C++ Microsoft  API,

tried using DXGI but it gives different values, also what is use of szDisplayMemoryEnglish

Comment: That should be DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.DedicatedVideoMemory

Answer (score 0):

See the [VideoMemory](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/VideoMemory) sample for a general overview of different ways to obtain VRAM information.

You can also use the `DxDiagProvider` API. See the [DxDiagOutput](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/DxDiag) sample.